# How to use the command xlswrite in a Mac version of MatLab?

Tags: java, excel, matlab, xls

When I use a Mac version of MatLab, I want to store a matrix into a '.xls' file. But it fails with a warnings saying that it could not start Excel server for export.

I was wondering if there is any solution to address this.

Comment: Are you sure you have MS Excel installed on your computer? I don't remember but I think none of the open source variants seem to work.

Comment: Yes, I indeed have a Mac Office installed.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB has been notorious for [not supporting this function on Mac](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2SJUON/index.html?solution=1-2SJUON). Look at [this blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/xlswrite-for-mac-linux/) or [this entry in FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37560-xlwrite-export-data-to-excel-from-matlab-on-macwin)

Alternately, you can use `csvwrite` to write a CSV file and import that to Excel. AFAIK, `csvwrite` is platform independent.

Comment: But I wanna to do some more computation and use the data to get some charts as the Excel can do. If I save the data into a CSV file, I don't think I can approach this object.

Comment: Thanks for the link to xlwrite. There is an improved version [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38591).

Answer (score 0):

From [MathWorks Solutions Support](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2SJUON/index.html?solution=1-2SJUON)  :

> The ability to use XLSWRITE on a Mac system to create Excel files is
>   not available in MATLAB 7.12 (R2011a). XLSWRITE instead creates CSV
>   (comma-separated value) files when used on a Mac, and provides the
>   same functionality as it does on Linux and UNIX platforms.
>
> The full functionality of XLSWRITE depends on the ability to
>   instantiate Microsoft Excel as a COM server. COM is a technology
>   developed for Windows platforms and is not available for the Mac. Thus
>   XLSWRITE as well as XLSREAD have limited functionality on the Mac
>   platform and work in basic mode.
>
> Support for XLSREAD on Mac OS X may be considered for a future release
>   of MATLAB. Unfortunately, there are no workarounds for the issue at
>   this time.